# как перенести строку из одного файла в другой системно в ruby?

Tags: ruby, sed

у меня есть массив который я получаю из файла

```
urls = IO.readlines("man.txt")
```

далее в цикле делаю что то

```
urls.each do |url|
  url = urls.at(i)

   some code..
   
  # записываю в новый файл текущую строку
  File.open('url__success.txt', 'a+'){ |file| file.write urls.at(i) }
  # в конце пытаюсь удалить текущую строку и заменить пустой системно
  system("sed -e 's/^/\n/' man.txt")


end
```

я получаю

> sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

хотя в чистом виде sed из консоли отрабатывает. любые другие варианты?
также я не хочу чтобы **url = urls.at(i)** эти значения сбивались по ходу выполнения цикла

Comment: `\\n`?.........

Comment: @Nakilon ``system("sed -e 's/^/\\n/' man.txt")``
так не работает, и в консоль идет вывод, ненужны

Comment: Ключ `-i` у sed что бы меня в файле, а не выводить в консоль

Comment: _На любом языке программирования можно программировать на Shell_. Совет: выучите Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общая практика трансформации данных не подразумевает удаление обработанной строки из файла. После обработки источник либо уходит в архив, либо просто удаляется, поэтому вся работа с ним сводится к чтению, остальное просто неудобно, зачастую бессмысленно и вдобавок это большие накладные расходы, потому что придется перезаписывать файл при каждом удалении строки почти целиком и если все внезапно сломается, то ты рискуешь получить пустой файл источника).

Может быть таким способом ты хочешь отслеживать прогресс операции? Если да, то можно гораздо проще: итерируйся по строкам с индексом `.each_with_index |row, idx|` и печатай индекс в консоль. Значение индекса будет являться количеством обработанных строк и в случае падения скрипта ты можешь начать с последнего значения индекса `.drop(567).each_with_index |val, idx|`. В этом примере цикл пропустит 567 строк и начнет с 568.